# Remove blank rows and associated ID in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame where I need to remove rows where a specific column (Score) is blank. Using the  below this is successful. However I need to add the stipulation to remove all rows with the associated ID, regardless of what those other rows contain in the Score column.

So I'm using:

```
df2 <- df1[!is.na(df1$Score), ]
```

Here is the data frame df1

```
ID  Score
123 4: M
123 NA
999 3: L
999 3: L
```

So, I'd end up with df2:

```
ID  Score
999 3: L
999 3: L
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group by 'ID' and `filter` the groups that have no `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   filter(all(!is.na(Score)))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   ID [1]
#     ID Score
#  <int> <chr>
#1   999 3: L 
#2   999 3: L
```

---

Or using `subset` from `base R`

```
subset(df1, !ID %in% unique(ID[is.na(Score)]))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(123L, 123L, 999L, 999L), Score = c("4: M", 
NA, "3: L", "3: L")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

With `base R`, you can use `ave()` and `subset()` to make it

```
df2 <- subset(df1,as.logical(ave(Score,ID, FUN = function(x) !any(is.na(x)))))
```

such that

```
> df2
   ID Score
3 999  3: L
4 999  3: L
```